# How to replace these characters "[" and "]" using regex?

Tags: android, regex

I have a string like this

```
String myString = "I love [stackoverflow]";
```

What I want to do is to replace the character `"["` to `<span style="color:red;">` and the character `"]"` to `</span>` to change the color of
the word `stackoverflow` to red.

So the expected string result is `"I love <span style="color:red;">stackoverflow</span>"`

I am new in regex so I tried like this

```
String myString = "I love [Stackoverflow]";

myString.replaceAll("[",<span style="color:red;">).replaceAll("]","</span>");
```

but seems not the correct way because the android studio says

> unclosed character class

What is the correct regex of that single character?

Comment: Did you try escaping `\\[`?

Comment: Don't use `replaceAll` since you're not even using regex. Use: `myString.replace("[",<span style="color:red;">).replace("]","</span>");`

Comment: I tried single slash `\[` but not the double slash `\\[`.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, I am a newbie in regex so I do not have an idea how regex works.

Comment: You can try my answer, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String myString = "I love [stackoverflow]";

    myString = myString.replace("[", "<b><font color=\"#FF0000\">").replace("]", "</font>");

    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    etEmail.setText(Html.fromHtml(myString));
```

[image: PLease check attached image...]